# select elements from rdd where for (x,y), (y,x) is present in the rdd

Tags: pyspark, rdd

I have the following rdd

```
[('K', ' M'),
 ('K', ' H'),
 ('M', ' K'),
 ('M', ' E'),
 ('H', ' F'),
 ('B', ' T'),
 ('B', ' H'),
 ('E', ' K'),
 ('E', ' H'),
 ('F', ' K'),
 ('F', ' H'),
 ('F', ' E'),
 ('A', ' Z')]
```

I want to filter out the elements (x,y) for which (y,x) is present in the rdd. In my example the output should be like:

```
[(K,M),
 (H,F)]
```

Thanks for help

Comment: Why is `('E', ' H')` not part of the expected output?

Comment: No, because there is no ```('H','E')``` in the input rdd

Comment: So you mean you want to retain `(x,y)` for which `(y,x)` does not exist?

Comment: I want to output ```(x,y)``` for which ```(y,x)``` exists. For example for, ```(K,M)``` and ```(M,K)``` exists. Similarly, for ```(H,F)``` , ```(F,H)``` exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put each tuple in order, count the tuples and then filter out tuples that have appeared more than once:

```
rdd.groupBy(lambda t: (min(t), max(t)))
   .mapValues(len)
   .filter(lambda t: t[1] > 1)
   .map(lambda t: t[0])
   .collect()

# [('F', 'H'), ('K', 'M')]
```

Comment: This does not give me the desired output. The output rdd is an empty rdd i.e. ```[]```

Comment: The 2nd element in each tuple has a space prefix. Is that intentional? I am assuming you have already cleaned that up.

Comment: what is this ```mapValues(len)``` doing here. If I do ```rdd.groupBy(lambda t: (min(t), max(t))).mapValues(len).collect()``` the output is ```[((' M', 'K'), 1),
 ((' H', 'K'), 1),
 ((' K', 'M'), 1),
 ((' E', 'M'), 1),
 ((' F', 'H'), 1),
 ((' T', 'B'), 1),
 ((' H', 'B'), 1),
 ((' K', 'E'), 1),
 ((' H', 'E'), 1),
 ((' K', 'F'), 1),
 ((' H', 'F'), 1),
 ((' E', 'F'), 1),
 ((' Z', 'A'), 1)]```. The ```mapValues(len)``` is giving 1 as output

Comment: It counts the length for each group.

Comment: o sorry you were right. I didn't clear that. Thanks!